# How to avoid overriding superclass initializer

Tags: swift, google-maps, oop, inheritance, initialization

I need to initialize `Place` object using the init method from its superclass `GMSMarker`. The problem is that `Place` also inherits an init method from `BaseModel` so that i can create object from JSON. I thought I would be able to call `GMSMarker`'s init method from within `BaseModel`'s init method but can't.

**Place**

```
class Place: BaseModel, GMSMarker {
    var imageUrl: String
    var name: String
    required convenience init?(json: [String : AnyObject] {
        // super.init(markerWithPosition:) // can't call GMSMarker init method.  
    }
}
```

**BaseModel**

```
protocol BaseModel {
    init?(json: [String : AnyObject])
    func toAnyObject() -> [String : AnyObject]?
}
```

**GMSMarker init definition**

```
/** Convenience constructor for a default marker. */
+ (instancetype)markerWithPosition:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)position;
```

Comment: First Place doesn't inherit anything from BaseModel as that is a protocol.  Place must conform to BaseModel define a init method the same.  Second that method in GMSMarker is not an initialiser it's a factory method that is called like this GMSMaker.markerWithPosition.  Third even if it saw an initialiser you need to call it with a parameter not just the name of the parameter.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Sir, you did not provide any constructive solution. Whether a `Place` object conforms to a protocol or inherits (term I wrongly used) from a class, doesn't change the fact that  `Place` contains the given init method. Perhaps Obj-C factory methods are somehow converted to initializers in swift. How else would I be able to call `Place(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D)` when I don't conform to `BaseModel`?  Also, "constructor" is typically analogous to "initializer". Lastly I know you need to include an input. I left it out for brevity, since it isn't recognized anyways.

Comment: Quite right which is why it's a comment and not an answer.  People reading this have no idea what you leave out for brevity so best to include everything so it doesn't get confused for part of the problem.  I was just trying to avoid people giving you pointless answers.  For example I can tell that the GMSMarker init definition is ObjectiveC but some people might not realise it so probably best to put it in the question somewhere.  You didn't mention you could call that but perhaps showing the entire definition of GMSMarker would help to clear up the issue.  Also what error are you getting?

Comment: Also I could argue the comment was constructive just not a solution because you have revealed that you can call `Place(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D)` which wasn't in the original question.  I'm only try to help you get the question answered but I can always move on to other things instead.

Comment: I understand, and thank you for taking the time out to be of service to others. The issue is that, within subclass `Place`, I cannot call init method of superclass `GMSMarker`. I wrote out a an arbitrary example to demonstrate this, and while doing so, I figured out what i was doing wrong. This got a couple up votes so ill just answer myself.

Comment: Ok no problem.  Many a time I have tried to explain a problem to someone only to figure out the solution as I explain it.  Glad you have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Create an initializer that calls init method of superclass (`GMSMarker`) & assigns value to any other properties like 'name'. Then when conforming to protocol initializer, just call initializer of self that you created.

example:

```
class Place: GMSMarker, BaseModel {
    var name: String
    // init
    init(lat: Double, long: Double, name: String) {
        // call init from GMSMarker superclass here.
        super.init(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.lat, longitude: self.long))
        self.name = name
    }

    // BaseModel init
    required convenience init?(json: [String : AnyObject]) {
        guard let lat = json["lat"] as? Double, let long = json["long"] as? Double, let name = json["name"] as? Sring else {
            return nil
        }
        // call init method of self inside BaseModel init.
        self.init(lat: lat, long: long, name: name)
    }
}
```